# how to seperate linux commands run from python

Tags: python, linux, adb

this is my code,the problem I'm facing is that only one code will run, in order for the next to work the first must be closed, how do I run both codes separately

```
if Start == "Y":
    print=("starting Scrcpy")
    import os
    os.system("./sndcpy.sh")
    import os
    os.system("scrcpy")
```

Comment: You only need to `import os` once. Does each command run if you remove the other from the python code?

Comment: scrcpy is a program launched from the terminal, and sndcpy is an extension of that run from an sh file, but i can run the command properly because in order to start the other linux command i have to stop the one that is currently running, but i want each code to run seperatley without interfering with each other

Answer (score 0):

You can use `multithreading` or `multiprocessing` module for that or add `&` to end of each command so they will run in the background, but I'm not sure if that's the best way though.

Comment: how would i use the multithreading command

Comment: You can create the `Thread` and then run command inside it, but after longer research I see that there is better way to do it. You can use `subprocess` module like that: `subprocess.Popen(['command', 'arg1'. 'arg2', ...])`

Comment: the command im using is infiniete as in it dosent end unless i physiclly turn it of